# kdb: guid encoding in c results in invalid serialization

Tags: kdb

I'm trying to manipulate guid from C++. Whenever I attempt to serialize a guid, I get a null pointer.

```
U g={0};
auto k = ku(g);
auto p = ::b9(2, k);
```

First two lines are straight from the manual for creating a null guid. This will result in p == 0.

Really what I was attempting to do was creating a list of guid and then serializing:

```
k = ktn(UU, 3)
kU(k)[0] = <an instance of U with the g bytes initialized>
kU(k)[1] = <an instance of U with the g bytes initialized>
kU(k)[2] = <an instance of U with the g bytes initialized>
```

That did not work when attempting to serialize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should be using `3` as the first argument to `b9`. For example:

```
jmcmurray@homer ~/c $ more test.c
#include"k.h"
K f(K x)
{
  K k = ktn(UU,3);I j=0;
  for(j=0;j<3;j++){
   U g={0};I i=0;
   for(i=j;i<j+16;i++){
    g.g[i] = (unsigned char)i;
   }
   kU(k)[0] = g;
  }
  return b9(3,k);
}
jmcmurray@homer ~/c $ gcc -shared -fPIC -DKXVER=3 test.c -o test.so
jmcmurray@homer ~/c $ q
KDB+ 3.5 2017.11.30 Copyright (C) 1993-2017 Kx Systems
l64/ 8()core 16048MB jmcmurray homer.aquaq.co.uk 192.168.1.57 EXPIRE 2019.06.30 AquaQ #52428

q)f:`:./test 2:(`f;1)
q)f[]
0x010000003e000000020003000000000002030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f00ae67af727f000..
q)-9!f[]
00000203-0405-0607-0809-0a0b0c0d0e0f 001868af-727f-0000-6062-67af727f0000 a0a..
q)
```

Here I am able to return a serialised list of GUIDs from my shared object & deserialize on the q side. When I tried with `2` as in your example I got a `'type` error when running the function in q.

According to https://code.kx.com/q/interfaces/capiref/#b9-serialize `3` means

> unenumerate, compress, allow serialization of timespan and timestamp

`2` is the same without "compress". So I guess you *must* compress GUIDs?